# Is there a way to optimize this x86 assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

Assume that you are given values in eax,ecx. Write a piece of code
that calculates 5*eax + 3*ecx + 1, and stores the result inside eax. (*
means multiplication here).

My code :

```
;Initialize the values in eax and ecx
mov eax,3
mov ecx,4
;Compute 3*ecx
mov ebx,eax
mov eax,ecx
mov edx,3
mul edx
; Compute 5*eax
mov ecx,eax
mov eax,ebx
mov edx,5
mul edx
; Compute 5*eax + 3*ecx + 1
lea eax,[ecx + eax]
inc eax
```

Comment: [godbolt example](https://goo.gl/GT7F5P)

Comment: Note that `imul` has forms with an `imm8` arg.  Of course, the `lea`, `lea`, `add` method will run faster.  If your factors didn't lend themselves to using `lea`, that would be useful.  (If signed multiply is ok, and you don't need the high 32 or high 64 of the result.)  Also, if I did need unsigned `mul`, I would have saved `mov` instructions by doing the `mul` of `eax` first, then moved the value aside.  *Then* move `ecx` to `eax` to setup for the next `mul`.  If values weren't already in regs, you could just delay loading the 2nd one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by *"optimize"* you mean optimize for instruction count, then sure, use `lea` even more:

```
;Initialize the values in eax and ecx
mov eax,3
mov ecx,4

;Compute 3*ecx
lea ecx,[ecx*2 + ecx]

; Compute 5*eax
lea eax,[eax*4 + eax]

; Compute 5*eax + 3*ecx + 1
lea eax,[ecx + eax + 1]
```

This is also 16 bytes less in machine code size if my eyes serve me right.

The rules governing what you can compute with `lea` are listed in the section **Specifying an offset** in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Thanks !! 
Just one more question, is wrong the way I did that? I mean, Should I focus in writing the code using less possible instructions?

Comment: If you're aiming to speed-optimize or size-optimize a piece of code, then pick the best instructions to reach that goal (note: fewer instructions doesn't necessarily mean smaller machine code or faster code). Otherwise, just write it in the way you find easiest to understand.

Comment: I'd always recommend making the code work *first* and then worrying about getting it optimized *where it makes sense to do so*, which would be based on where the code is actually spending most of its time.  Experience has shown me that it is very easy to optimize the 98% of the code that doesn't actually impact the majority of the execution time. :)

Answer (score 5):

Michael's (most excellent) solution can yet be slightly optimized for size (1 byte shorter), but this requires a little algebraic manipulation first.

```
  5*eax + 3*ecx + 1
= 2*eax + 3*eax + 3*ecx + 1
= 2*eax + 3*(eax + ecx) + 1
```

This can be solved via ...

```
(Excluding initialization of EAX and ECX)
add ecx, eax                  ; 2 bytes
lea ecx,[ecx*2 + ecx]         ; 3 bytes
lea eax,[eax*2 + ecx + 1]     ; 4 bytes
```

Comment: Nice, but this will run slower because there's only one linear dependency chain.  Complex `LEA` instructions on recent Intel CPUs run with 3 cycle latency, 1/cycle throughput.  (Simple `LEA` runs 1c latency, 2/cycle throughput.)  What if you just do the `+1` as part of one of the LEAs, and `add` at the end?

Comment: @PeterCordes - Thanks for the speed analysis.  It is good to draw attention to the fact that optimizing for size and optimizing speed can yield different code.

Comment: `lea ecx, [ecx*2+ecx+1]  /  lea eax, [eax*4+eax]  / add eax,ecx`  is as small as yours, but the two LEAs can run in parallel, so with more work you can sometimes do both.  I don't see a way around using a 3-component addressing mode, though, which makes LEA 3 cycle latency instead of 1.  (`eax*4+eax` is still 1 cycle; the +1 makes it 3 cycles, on Intel SnB.)  Yours should be `1+1+3 = 5` latency, but mine is only 4.  My other point was that you didn't need the algebraic rearrangement, just move the +1 into an op that already has to be an LEA.